# Sticky and glossy paint touch up

Tags: repair, painting

I used the Command brand of picture hanging strips to hang a picture. When I took it down, it peeled off a small spot of paint. I tried to touch it up using a small paint brush. The area that ripped off looks the same color but around the edges, where I got some paint on the paint that was already there, is sticky and very shiny even after 24 hours. The paint is an oil based satin paint. Is there anything that I can do to fix the shiny, sticky area?

Comment: It sounds like the paint soaked into the bare patch but is drying slowly on the painted surface. Give it another day to see if the stickiness goes away. The final gloss level make take several days.

Answer (score 1):

Only a guess but maybe you had some of the adhesive still on the wall and painted over it causing the sticky feel. If so, you may need to sand it very carefully just over the touched up spot and surrounding 1/4 inch to ensure the area is smooth. Dust off with a dry soft cloth or dusting brush and try touching it up again just over the sanded area. I would use 180grit or 240 grit where oil based paint is concerned. You may even try wet and dry paper with a little water to lubricate the sanding.

Touch ups are hard to get right but don't worry, you do need to make it ugly before it becomes beautiful and sometimes when you try to touch up a postage stamp sized area and the whole wall is only 30 square feet, believe it or not, it can be easier to just bite the bullet and paint the whole wall.